# UpsertDocumentAsync returns 204 "no content"

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

UpsertDocumentAsync and CreateDocumentAsync stopped working for some reason.
I'm executing this line:

```
_client.UpsertDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId), new { MyProperty = "A Value" });
```

and get response 204 (No Content). According to MSDN only DELETE operation returns this status code. databaseId and collectionId are correct. What might be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I made my Web API method Async and it fixed the problem.

```
public async Task<Document> Post(dynamic doc)
{
    return await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId), doc);
}
```